The composer does not work in PhpStorm. error ('""' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file)
I have composer installed and it works fine in cmd, PowerShell, PyCharm:

but not working in PhpStorm:

error: '""' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file


Reinstalling or adjusting "Environment Variables" doesn't help. Composer works in other terminals but this command does not work in PhpStorm.

The solution to this is very simple, see the picture
I searched for this solution for a long time. When I compared the settings of pycharm and phpstorm I noticed that phpstorm has several additional features. these functions were missing in pycharm and pycharm consolida composer works. I wanted to share this after finding this answer and created a question on this very topic and will answer it myself.
If you need this feature and you don't want to disable it, I found 2 more solutions and they are as follows.

You need to select another terminal program in phpstorm. it should be as follows in widows. see

put composer.phar where you want to work and use "php composer.phar update" instead of "composer update".
command "composer" === "php composer.phar"


